# How to use 'group_by()' in R to make sure columns are of equal length?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

1. I have a data frame with with stock market data in 3 columns: **1-Date, 2-Price, 3-Symbol**.
2. The Symbol column is different stock tickers.
3. I am trying to get the **Price** ratio of any given two or more of **Symbol**s for any given time frame.
4. But, not all Symbols have data going back as far as others, so...
5. Can I use something like, **group_by(Data)** then drop any ungrouped rows?

Here, **allTickerData** is the the main data frame and I filter that by the users choice of what ticker to be the denominator of our ratio.

```
DenominatedTicker <- allTickerData %>% dplyr::filter(., symbol == input$DenomTickerChoice)
```

Then we make a new column in our main data frame, **RatioPrice** that gets every ticker's price divided by the users choice of denominator.

But, I am trying to do this ONLY where the dates match and would like to drop any ungrouped dates (dates will already be sorted).

**UserTickerChoices** is a list of tickers selected by the user.

```
activeTickerDataByDate <- allTickerData %>% dplyr::filter(., symbol == input$UserTickerChoices) %>% group_by(., date) %>% dplyr::mutate(., RatioPrice=(Price/DenominatedTicker$Price))
```

Thank you!

```
> dput(head(allCoinData))
structure(list(slug = c("bitcoin", "bitcoin", "bitcoin", "bitcoin", 
"bitcoin", "bitcoin"), symbol = c("BTC", "BTC", "BTC", "BTC", 
"BTC", "BTC"), name = c("Bitcoin", "Bitcoin", "Bitcoin", "Bitcoin", 
"Bitcoin", "Bitcoin"), date = structure(c(17167, 17168, 17169, 
17170, 17171, 17172), class = "Date"), ranknow = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), open = c(963.66, 998.62, 1021.6, 1044.4, 1156.73, 1014.24
), high = c(1003.08, 1031.39, 1044.08, 1159.42, 1191.1, 1046.81
), low = c(958.7, 996.7, 1021.6, 1044.4, 910.42, 883.94), close = c(998.33, 
1021.75, 1043.84, 1154.73, 1013.38, 902.2), volume = c(147775008, 
222184992, 185168000, 344945984, 510199008, 351876000), market = c(16050407461, 
16429024775, 16786368910, 18571869009, 16300254795, 14513695758
), close_ratio = c(0.892969806219017, 0.722110118189679, 0.989323843416365, 
0.95922448269866, 0.366823428815733, 0.112113955915761), spread = c(44.38, 
34.69, 22.48, 115.02, 280.68, 162.87)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: its easier if you include a reproducible sample of your data using the `dput()` command. Otherwise its hard to help you

Comment: I should have generalized by asking: 

How to do a vectorized operation on two different sized dataframes after grouping by a common variable.

Comment: I just tried the dput() and it outputs very large amounts of data so I think too big to paste here.

Comment: Please `dput(head(allTickerData))`

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to answer if you share a  [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). You can try the below answer :

```
library(dplyr)

DenominatedTicker <- allTickerData %>% filter(symbol == input$DenomTickerChoice)
#Get common dates
common_dates <- Reduce(intersect,split(allTickerData$Date, allTickerData$symbol))

#Filter those common_dates and then calculate the ratio.
result <- allTickerData %>%
            filter(Date %in% common_dates) %>%
            mutate(RatioPrice= Price/DenominatedTicker$Price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that uses `pivot_wider`. First, we generate some random data (as you didn't share any):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(0)

allTickerData = sample(fruit, 5) %>%
  map(~tibble(Symbol = .x,
              Price = abs(cumsum(rnorm(str_length(.x)))),
              Date = seq(today() - str_length(.x), today() - 1, length.out = str_length(.x)))) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Then, we can use `pivot_wider` to pivot the data into a form where each ticker has its own column, where we can use `filter(across())` to remove rows that contain `NA`. Afterwards, we use `pivot_longer` to get the original data shape back:

```r
allTickerData %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Symbol, Date),
                names_from = Symbol,
                values_from = Price) %>%
    filter(across(-Date, ~!is.na(.x))) %>%
    pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "Symbol", values_to = "Price")
```

You can then use `mutate` on this to get your `RatioPrice`.